# Java: saving to a variable vs multiple function calls

Tags: java

I have a method where it takes in an object as an input

```
void doSomething(MyObject myObj) {
   ///
}
```

In this method, it calls `myObj.getValue()` several times for various reasons

Is it better to just store as `int objValue = myObj.getValue()` and use `objValue` throughout the method, instead keep calling `myObj.getValue()`

why? why not?

Comment: It entirely depends on what `getValue` does.  If it accesses a final field or other clearly fixed property the JIT compiler will optimise that away most of the time.  If it actually runs some computation then it will rerun the computation each time.

Comment: @user2478398 no computation. it's just a parameter of a constructor stored via \@Getters annotation

Comment: always its a better way even its easier during refactor `int objValue = myObj.getValue()`

Comment: Avoid premature optimization and strive to [write dumb code](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/devinsight-1-139780.html)

Comment: Other thing to consider whether that value which is returned by `myObj.getValue()` could be changed by other threads.

Comment: If you can afford to declare the field as final, then no need to store it into a temporary. The compiler can optimize it. If it is not final then storing it into a temporary may give you some efficiency.

Comment: As long as you are not planning on changing the value, I would call it once and store. Not for any potential optimizations, just because it's a bit easier to read that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If getValue() is a timeconsuming operation it will most likely be better to call it once only and store the value in a variable.

If you call it several times, you might not in practice get any performance improvements, depending on compiler optimizations.